# Rails render nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass a variable from controller to view page

My controller is

```
class MapsController < ApplicationController
    def maps
        @outlet = Brand.all
        render "maps/map"
    end
end
```

my view page is

```
<%= debug @outlet %>
```

my route is

```
  get 'maps/map' => 'maps#map'
```

my database is

```
id   brand_id
 1     hello
 2     hi
 3     this_is _some_text
```

why i receive the followoing as the input, instead of the database?

```
--- 
...
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your question is not clear >>> why i receive the followoing as the input, instead of the database? <<<

Comment: `<%= debug @outlet %>` is this content of `maps/map` template?

Comment: Can you post output of `Brand.all` from rails console into your question?

Comment: Shouldn't `get 'maps/map' => 'maps#map'` be `get 'maps/map' => 'maps#maps'`? You didn't show us `map` action in your controller.

Comment: your route  is get `'maps/map' => 'maps#map'` and action name is `maps`  confirm it. and also confirm the views file name is `map.ext`

Comment: I'm trying to pass a variable from controller to view page,.. how can i do that/

Comment: Is your view file named "map.html.erb" and in the maps view folder?  Also, try <%= @outlet.inspect %>  
in your view and let us know exactly what the output is!

Comment: it's named `map.html.erb` only... I received `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the name of the method in your controller from maps to map and then your view should be map.html.erb

when you do get 'maps/map' => 'maps#map' rails will look for a method called map in your maps controller. the best you can do, is to check your routes with
bundle exec rake routes